# Single AWS Elastic Load Balancer to multiple EC2 instance pools?

Tags: amazon-elb

Does AWS Elastic Load Balancer support having a single load Balancer to multiple EC2 Instance Pools?

I have three domains:

- www.example.com
- api.example.com
- stats.example.com

And I'd like to serve them all behind a single load balancer, but with different EC2 instances. My Web site gets ultra light traffic, my api servers get light-traffic, and my stats servers get heavy traffic. So I'd like to have three pools of (1,2,4) instances if possible, all behind a single load balancer (and a single elastic-ip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need separate ELBs for each group.

Answer (score 2):

For sites that get light and ultra-light traffic, there is no need to give them there own instance. You might save money and simplify the architecture by having one ELB and once set of redundant instances that each serve the "www", "api" and "stats" subdomains as virtual hosts on the same instances.

Note though that you can currently only have one SSL certificate per ELB. However, a single wildcard certificate could address this, or a multi-domain certificate that covers all three domains.